# How to assign a time value from a textbox to a variable?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, time, stopwatch

I'm trying to figure out how to set the hours,minutes,seconds & milliseconds values from a text box to a long variable so that I can manipulate the time value in an application.

What I have tried so far is creating a long variable called 'workTime' but I'm not sure how I would assign the value entered into the text box as a period of time.

For example if the user entered "00 : 02 : 30 : 000", how would I assign this to a variable?

Is it possible to assign a time value in this manner?

Any advice or alternative methods would be much appreciated.

```
private void startBtn_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {


            string wrkString;
            string rstString; 
            int i;

            //Assign text box time string to string variables.
            wrkString = wrkTbx.Text;
            rstString = restTbx.Text;


            //Assign text box string value to a date time variable.

            DateTime workDt = DateTime.ParseExact(wrkString.Replace(": ", ":").Replace(" :", ":"), "HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            DateTime restDt = DateTime.ParseExact(rstString.Replace(": ", ":").Replace(" :", ":"), "HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


            StopGoCvs.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            hornElmt.Play();
            //    // set up the timer
            myTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            myTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
            myTimer.Tick += myTimer_Tick;

            //tell timer to stop when it has reached the allocated work time.
            if(myTimer.Interval != workDt.TimeOfDay)
            {
                // start both timers
                myTimer.Start();
                myStopwatch.Start();

            }
            else
            {
                myTimer.Stop();
                myStopwatch.Stop();

            }



        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time.Replace(": ", ":").Replace(" :", ":"), "HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You are missing the spaces before and after the `:`. And, a duration(`TimeSpan`) fits more into the situation than a `DateTime`.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 - I updated my answer to account for any spaces that might be before or after the colons. However, I'm standing by my choice of `DateTime` because `TimeSpan` is more of a measure of elapsed time or a duration of time. From his description, it sounds like its a time of day.

Comment: "workTime" and "as a period of time" seem to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 - "workTime" seems to suggest to me that he is referring to a time of day. For example, he starts his work job at 3:00pm. What we should do is just ask the OP.

Comment: @icemanind is the 'time' variable referring to the contents of the textbox?

Comment: @BrianJ -- Yes. The time string that contains "00 : 02 : 30 : 000" from your example.

Comment: @icemanind I set up the above code and it correctly assigns the string value to the date time variable. But I'm wondering how I would call myStopwatch to stop when it reaches said date time value. For example, I enter 20 seconds then timer object stops. I tried using a while(myStopwatch != dt) but it seems you can't use this opperand with this.

Comment: @BrianJ - What kind of variable is myStopwatch?

Comment: @icemanind myStopwatch is a variable of type Stopwatch from System.Diagnostics

Comment: @BrianJ - Stopwatch might not be the right tool for this job. Stopwatch is designed to be started, then stopped, then return the time between the stop and start. A [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0wdddfy(v=vs.110).aspx) might be more what you are looking for, where you can specify the number of milliseconds to stop the timer.

Comment: I have a 'DispatcherTimer myTimer;' ,could I use my Datetime variable 'dt' to signal myTimer to stop when it reaches the value stored in 'dt'? I was thinking of something like 'while(myTimer.Interval != restDt)' but it seems I can't use this operand in that way.

Comment: @BrianJ - Yes. Assign the Millisecond property of the DateTime to the interval property of myTimer.

Comment: I tried the following ' myTimer.Interval != restDt.Millisecond;' and got a conversion error : 'Cannot implicitly convert type int to System.TimeSpan' My aim is to call stop on the clock when the myTimer.Interval reaches the time stored in restDt.

Comment: @BrianJ - Use this: `myTimer.Interval != restDt.TimeOfDay`

Comment: Tried the above fix but I'm still getting a 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'

Comment: yeah sure, I'll append it to my original question.

Comment: I've added a code snippet from my button_tapped event where I call the timer to start. The timer itself runs fine but when I try to call it to stop when it reaches the length of time stored in workDt it freezes up. No compiler errors.

Comment: @BrianJ - take out the while loop

Comment: @icemanind I've started a new question related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177769/how-to-stop-a-timer-object-after-a-set-interval-of-time

Answer (score 1):

```
//using System.Globalization

TimeSpan.ParseExact("00 : 02 : 30 : 000", @"%h\ \:\ %m\ \:\ %s\ \:\ %fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat)
//from here you can decide to store the timespan value or the miliseconds via its 'TotalMilliseconds' property.


//It may help with readability by removing the space from the input
TimeSpan.ParseExact("00 : 02 : 30 : 000".Replace(" ", ""), @"%h\:%m\:%s\:%fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat)
```